# In the category $\mathbf{Mod}_R$, how do you show that kernels and cokernels exist?

Tags: category-theory

I understand the definition of the kernel of a morphism, $f:A\to B$, say, in an additive category. It is a morphism $i: K \to A$ such that $fi=0$ and is universal with the property that if $j:K' \to A$ is another morphism such that $fj=0$, then there is a unique morphism $g:K'\to K$ such that $j=ig$.

I want to know how do you show the morphism $i$ always exists for any $f$ in this category?

It is written [here](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~ums/pdf/Rankeya_R-mod_and_Abelian_Categories.pdf) that the inclusion $i : ker(f) \to A$ is the kernel of $f$ in the sense of definition above in this category, however, I don't know how to show this. I'm confused about whether one simply begins by saying $f(i(x)) = f(0) = 0$? But then doesn't this presupposes $i$ is the kernel of $f$ before we've proven it is a kernel? Wouldn't this work in any other category also then?

Comment: The point is, there's this abstract categorical concept of kernel, then there's the one we're familiar with before categories. You need to take the definition of kernel from basic algebra, and show it satisfies the "categorical definition" of being a kernel. In particular, if you let $i:\ker(f)\to A$ be the inclusion of the kernel, then $fi=0$ by definition. So all you need to show is the universal property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Category of modules is concrete category: we have sets with additional structure. It makes sense to write down $\ker f=\{x\in M\,|\, f(x) = 0\}$ in ${\bf{Mod}}_R$ for some $f\colon M\to N$, but obviously not in categories that are not concrete. You want to confirm that $i\colon \ker f\to M$ is kernel in categorical sense. Note that $i$ is defined by $i(x) = x$.

First of all, $f(i(x)) = f(x) = 0$, for all $x\in\ker f$, by defintion of $\ker f$ and thus $f\circ i = 0$. Furthermore, take $g\colon M'\to M$ such that $f\circ g = 0$. That means that for all $x\in M'$ we have $f(g(x)) = 0$ which implies that $g(x)\in\ker f$, for all $x\in M'$. Thus, $g$ factors as $M'\to\ker f\stackrel{i}{\to}M$. It is trivial to confirm that this factorization is unique.

Comment: I think I understand more clearly now. Thanks so much for your help.